# Bash Script with if, elif, else

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

Okay so this is an assignment so I will not put in the exact script here but I am really desperate at this point because I cannot figure something as basic as if's. So I am basically checking if the two arguments that are written in the command line are appropriate (user needs to type it correctly) or it will echo a specific error message. However, when I put in a command with 100% correct arguments, I get the error echo message from the first conditional ALWAYS (even if I switch around the conditional statements). It seems that the script just runs the first echo and stops no matter what. Please help and I understand it might be hard since my code is more of a skeleton.

```
 if [ ... ]; then
 echo "blah"

 elif [ ... ]; then
 echo "blah2"

else for file; do
#change file to the 1st argument

done 
fi
```

I obviously need the last else to happen in order for my script to actually serve its intended purpose. However, my if-fy problem is getting in the way. The if and elif need to return false in order for the script to run for appropriate arguments. The if and elif check to see if the person typed in the command line correctly.

Comment: You probably need to show the tests you're making, because if valid arguments are meaning you don't get to the `else` block, it probably means you've got your tests inverted (you need to check `if arg1 is invalid then echo blah blah 1 elif arg2 is invalid then echo blah bletch 2 else … fi`.

Comment: What is the actual code you run where you show `...`? That's really the most relevant detail here.

Answer (score 2):

elif mean else-if. So it only will only be checked if the first statement returns false. So if you want to check if both are correct do.

```
if [ ... ] then
...
fi

if [ ... ] then
...
fi
```

Comment: What are you doing in the `...` in the body of those statements?  The `if`…`elif`…`else` has some better properties than this unless you exit the script in your `...` body statements.  And it would be preferable to leave spaces around the `[` and `]` since those are _crucial_ in shell programming.

Comment: @jonathan I agree that for his purposes, the structure you suggested is the best, but you won't be able to echo that both arguments are wrong by doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

When you care about checking **both** the *first* and *second* command line arguments for a *single* condition (i.e. they must both meet a set of criteria for the condition to be true), then you will need a compound test construct like:

```
if [ "$1" = somestring -a "$2" = somethingelse ]; then
    do whatever
fi
```

which can also be written

```
if [ "$1" = somestring ] && [ "$2" = somethingelse ]; then
...
```

**Note:** the `[ .... -a .... ]` syntax is still supported, but it is recommended to use the `[ .... ] && [ .... ]` syntax for new development.

You can also vary the way they are tested (either true/false) by using `-o` for an **OR** condition or `||` in the second form. You can further vary your test using different test expressions (i.e. `=`, `!=`, `-gt`, etc..)

Comment: *Should* be written `[ ... ] && [ ... ]`. `-a` is supported for historical reasons but is not recommended for new code.

Comment: Agreed, that is why both versions were given. I guess the emphasis should be more clear.